# C scanf() returns -1

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

```
int input;
printf("Type in an odd number less than or equal to 9: \n");

int correctInput = 0;
do {
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if((input % 2) == 0) {
        printf("You have not entered an odd number. Please try again. \n");
    }
    else if(input > 9 || input < 1) {
        printf("Your input is not from 1 to 9. Please try again. \n");
    }
    else {
        correctInput = 1;
    }
} while(correctInput == 0);

printf("Input: %f. \n", input);
```

All I want to do is get an odd integer from 1-9 into the input variable. However when I run this code and enter in something like 7, I get

```
Type in an odd number less than or equal to 9:
3
Input: -1.#QNAN0.
```

Comment: `"Input: %f..."` format string is wrong for `int input`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("Input: %f. \n", input);
```

use this instead:

```
printf("Input: %d. \n", input);
```

`f` conversion specifier is to print `double` values, use `d` conversion specifier to print `int` values.

Answer (score 3):

`input` is of integer type. Please try with `printf("Input: %d. \n", input);`

Answer (score 2):

This line is not correct:

```
printf("Input: %f. \n", input);
```

The variable `input` is of `int` type so you should use the `%d` formatting sequence:

printf("Input: %d. \n", input);

Answer (score 0):

Following is the correct syntax,
printf("Input: %d. \n", input);

format specifier %d stands for integers.